# jqGrid + Internet Explorer 5 Quirks Mode

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to make jqGrid work in IE5 Quirks Mode in IE10.

I am using jqGrid verison 4.4.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid don't support Quirks Mode and it don't support IE5 too.

I don't see any reason why one should simulate it in IE10. You can start developer tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) and choose in the menu "Document Mode" the IE5 Quirks, but in the mode will not work the most jQuery Plugins inclusive jqGrid.